# onCreateOptionsMenu does not appear

Tags: android, menu, tabs

My application have something like this:

```
TabActivity
    Tab 1 (ActivityGroup)
        Activity > Activity > MapActivity
    Tab 2 (ActivityGroup)
        MapActivity
```

The problem is that in the **Tab 2 MapActivity** the options menu does not appear, even displays an error. But in the first **MapActivity** works perfectly. I put a breakpoint inside the method `onCreateOptionsMenu` but even entered it.

I used this [tutorial](http://androidgenuine.com/?p=375) for make my application based in TabHost.

Could anyone help me to know why in one works and the other not?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

About version:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

First MapActivity class:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 1, "Nearest");
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Directions");
    return true;
}
```

Second MapActivity class:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, 0, 1, "Nearest");
    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Region");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a bit of code? Where do you call the onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: Please add your onCreateOptions code. Also, what version of Android are you targeting/running this app on?

Comment: I updated the question. Platform is 2.3.3, API level 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically a `TabHost` only has one options menu.

I haven't tested it, but my guess would be that it's just using the first activity that returns true from `onCreateOptionsMenu`.  If you want a different options menu for each tab, you'll have to do several things:

1) Subclass `TabHost` and override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

2) When the tab changes (can't remember how you listen for this event, google it), call `invalidateOptionsMenu`, which will force a call to `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

3) In `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, remember to call `menu.clear()`, and then do the normal menu inflation stuff that you do in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to create your tab specific options menu.